# как нарисовать фрагмент спрайта на java

Tags: java

[image]

Вот мне нужно нарисовать Game over. Что для этого нужно указывать

Comment: Ничего не понял, давай разберёмся) drawString() устроит?

Answer (score 0):

```
//загружаем изображение
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
//обрезаем
// getSubimage( x, y, width, height)
image = image.getSubimage( 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Для интерфейса Android это так же реализуется?